# Add and copy row when matching

Tags: vba, excel

I am playing around with Macros in Excel 2016. What I want is to add a row under a row containing the text "name" and if that's the case copy the row contents under it. What I tried so far:

```
Sub InsertNewRow()
    Dim c As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H654")
    For dblCounter = Rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Rng(dblCounter)
        If c.Value Like "*Name*" Then
            c.EntireRow.Insert

    End If
    Next dblCounter
End Sub
```

[image: excel2016 macro]

The question is how to add a new row (see above code) and copy the full contents of the row above into it.

Comment: OK, and your question is ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to allways use `Option Explicit` at the top, and declare all your variables.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertNewRow()

    Dim c As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim dblCounter As Long

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H654")
    For dblCounter = Rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Rng(dblCounter)
        If c.Value Like "*Name*" Then
            c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert ' insert a row below
            c.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Range("A" & c.Row + 1) ' copy the contents from the row above
        End If
    Next dblCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding a new row works. Copying the contents from the row above doesn't.

Comment: @CitizenSP what do you mean by "not working" ? are you getting an error ? is it copying the wrong row ? copying nothing ?

Comment: @CitizenSP just tested it a few times, it works on my file